# How to completely dismiss mv error in a makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, mv

I'm trying to move all hidden files with suffix `.gcov` to another directory in makefile. What I tried:

`@-mv -f .*.gcov target_dir`

The build won't stop because of the `-` in front of `mv`. However, there is still an error message shown up in the terminal during this process.

```
mv: cannot stat ‘.*.gcov’: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to even dismiss this message? Or is there a convenient way to check if there is any hidden file suffixed `.gcov` prior to the move?

Comment: try `@-mv -f .*.gcov target_dir > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks! That's really close, but it still shows something is wrong: `make[2]: [coverage] Error 1 (ignored)`.

Comment: How about: `@-mv -f .*.gcov target_dir 2> /dev/null || true`

Comment: `@find * -maxdepth 0 -name .*.gcov -exec mv {} target_dir \;` will also do it

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
@-mv -f .*.gcov target_dir 2> /dev/null || true
```

Taken from [Kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum)'s comment.